# I am getting 'tuple' object is not callable as an error

Tags: python, stack, push, callable

```
brackets = set([(()())])
Stack = []
StackSize = 20
ch=(['(',')'])
arr=[]
```

Here I have generated a set of brackets which is showing an error. How can it be corrected?

Comment: For future reference you ought to have told us which line the error happened on, and since it's the first one you probably didn't need to show us the others. But you've got some good answers now!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `tuple` inside your expression is being called using another tuple expression `()`

```
>>> ()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
>>>
```

I think you want to create a string similar to following as string values.
For example:

```
   >>> brackets = set('[','(','()','()',')',']')
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`brackets = set('[','(','(',')','(',')',')',']')`